# JavaScript: For loop array in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to create a variable which store array in array by for loop to pass chart data to a chart.

Consider I have some JSON data and I am trying to acquire all the data with the below process

```
var FansChart = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 33; j++) {
             FansChart.push({
                name : url[i],
                data : data.result[i].trendData[j].value, //api thing doesn't really matter
              });
            }
        }
```

but it seem I am using the wrong method, how can I correct this?

I wish to be able to call something like:

```
data.result[2].trendData[23].value
```

UPDATE one:

```
var abc =[];
            var FansChart = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < data.result[0].trendData.length; j++) {
                        abc.push(data.result[i].trendData[j].value);
                    }
                  FansChart.push({
                    name : url[i],
                    data : abc

                  });
                  }
```

I have update my method like above is more like what i want to do, but i realize that all the trendDate have been bonded to varaible abc, how may i separate them?

JSON

```
errorCode: null,
message: "Success",
result: [{
    urlId: "a279ab1177ab8d7011466e77b79b98f7",
    trendData: [],
    url: "https://www.instagram.com/p/BFQGk2WER56/?taken-by=fishfung_saimei&hl=en"
}, {
    urlId: "a279ab1177ab8d7011466e77b79b98f7",
    trendData: [{
        date: "2016-06-04",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-21",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-12",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-05",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-07",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-19",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-25",
        value: 1527
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-25",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-11",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-15",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-08",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-27",
        value: 1527
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-27",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-06",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-29",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-09",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-03",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-17",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-24",
        value: 1527
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-24",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-13",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-22",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-01",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-14",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-18",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-26",
        value: 1527
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-26",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-20",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-10",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-23",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-28",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-02",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-16",
        value: 0
    }],
    url: "https://www.instagram.com/p/BFQGk2WER56/?taken-by=fishfung_saimei&hl=en"
}, {
    urlId: "a279ab1177ab8d7011466e77b79b98f7",
    trendData: [{
        date: "2016-06-04",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-21",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-12",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-05",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-07",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-19",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-25",
        value: 1527
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-25",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-11",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-15",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-08",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-27",
        value: 1527
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-27",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-06",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-29",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-09",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-03",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-17",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-24",
        value: 1527
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-24",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-13",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-22",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-01",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-14",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-18",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-26",
        value: 1527
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-26",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-20",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-10",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-23",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-28",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-02",
        value: 0
    }, {
        date: "2016-06-16",
        value: 0
    }],
    url: "https://www.instagram.com/p/BFQGk2WER56/?taken-by=fishfung_saimei&hl=en"
}],
```

Comment: Give us your `data` code?

Comment: you should change either variable name of `data : data.result[i].trendData[j].value`

Answer (score 0):

Convert i to j in for :

Change :

```
for (var j = 0; j < 33; i++) {
```

to :

```
for (var j = 0; j < 33; j++) {
```

Comment: Sorry i missed it but it's just my question, i do have semicolon in my actual code and it's not working

Comment: @anson920520 you mistake in for.convert i to j.

Comment: @anson920520 , you In the loop not increase value j . i updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a semicolon at the 2nd line. It should be `for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {`

Comment: Sorry i missed it but it's just my question, i do have semicolon in my actual code and it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Here you go..

```
FansChart.push({
            name : url[i],
            data : data.result[i].trendData[j].value // no comma here
          });
```

Remove the comma in `data : data.result[i].trendData[j].value` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Remove i++ from second for loop

```
var FansChart = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 33; j++) {
         FansChart.push({
            name : url[i],
            data : data.result[i].trendData[j].value //api thing doesn't really matter
          });
        }
    }
```

I hope it will work for you.